# Gravtiy Forms API User Submitted Post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, titanium, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form set up (through gravity forms) that allows users to upload a post with custom fields directly into WordPress, which all works beautifully! 
However, I have now set up the Gravity forms API to allow submissions from a Titanium built app, and while I can submit some data successfully and see it in the 'Entries' tab in WordPress, it is not published as a post.

Is this a limitation of the Gravity Forms API, or something I have missed? 
While I'm sure this functionality could be replicated with hooks, this is something that Gravity Forms automates already so I feel it should be something that is possible!

Here is the code in case it helps:

```
var postParams = [{
    1 : 'Test Data',
    2 : 'Test Data',
    3 : 'Test Data',
    4 : 'Test Data',
    5 : 'Test Data',
    6 : 'Test Data',
    7 : 'Test Data',
    8 : 'Test Data',
    9 : 'Test Data',    
}];

var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();    

xhr.onload = onComplete;
xhr.onerror = onComplete;

xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(postParams));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an entry using the API currently does not trigger the post creation, notification and confirmation functions. You can using the following to trigger the post creation.

```
RGFormsModel::create_post( $form, $entry );
```

Comment: Is there an API specific hook to add this in? Thank for your help! =)